Error: System error: 3000: assert(required <= maxAvailable()) failed - file: rtlcommon.hpp, line 137 (in Disk Read G1 E2) (0, 0), 3000,
I am working on ECL IDE and getting this error while submitting this program to ECL Watch. Here is the code:
IMPORT STD;
EXPORT File_Image := MODULE
 EXPORT imageRecord := RECORD
  STRING filename;
  DATA   image;   
//First 4 bytes contain the length of the image data
  UNSIGNED8  RecPos{virtual(fileposition)};
 END;
 EXPORT imageData := DATASET('~online::nt::skina', imageRecord, FLAT);
 //Add RecID and Dependent Data
 EXPORT imageRecordPlus := RECORD
   UNSIGNED1 RecID; 
   UNSIGNED1 YType;
   imageRecord;
 END;
 
  EXPORT imageDataPlus := PROJECT(imageData, 
                                     TRANSFORM(imageRecordPlus,
                                               SELF.RecID := COUNTER,
                                                                                                               SELF.YType := IF(STD.STR.Find(LEFT.filename,'dog')<> 0,1,0),;
                                                                                                                               SELF.Image := LEFT.IMAGE[51..],
                                                                                                                                  SELF := LEFT)); 
                                                                                                                                         
END;


The code you are submitting does not seem to have any actions, for example, an OUTPUT action. Create a new file in your folder and try this code:
IMPORT $;
$.File_Image.imageData;

Just to make sure your file definition is correct. You also do not need the
UNSIGNED8  RecPos{virtual(fileposition)};
Comment that out.
The error itself usually means that your file is the wrong type, but FLAT should be the type after a BLOB spray.
Regards,
Bob
